# ¿Cómo puedo centrar el título de una card en Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap

No logro centrar el header de este form, estoy trabajando con Bootstrap por primera vez, quisiera que quede todo centrado como en el prototipo (imagen #2)

[image: Así está]

[image: Debería quedar así]

Este es todo el CSS:

```
.login-header {
  background: radial-gradient(
    95.14% 7284.37% at 2.57% 20%,
    #ffc24b 0%,
    #ffa13a 100%
  );

  width: 350px;
  height: 40px;
}
.login-header,
.login p {
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #444444;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13.0408px;
}

#regForm {
  height: 500px;
  width: 350px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 100px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Este es el código HTML del form:

```
<div class="container" id="regForm">
  <h2 class="login-header rounded-top ">
    ¡Registrese y obtenga los libros que más quiera!
  </h2>
  <form class="box pt-4 text-lg-start">
    <input class="rounded" type="text" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" />
    <input type="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" />
    <input
      type="password"
      placeholder="Contraseña"
      id="password"
      required
    />
    <input
      type="password"
      placeholder="Confirmar contraseña"
      id="confirm_password"
      required
    />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning shadow p-2 rounded" id="submit">
      Registrarse
    </button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="submit">
      Google button
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Muchas gracias y felices fiestas.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar la clase `card` de Bootstrap ya que esta dispone de algunas de las propiedades css que utilizaste en `#regForm`. Son muchas las razones por las que no obtienes el resultado que buscas, por ejemplo no usaste ni `row` ni `col` que son dos clases útiles al posicionamiento de los elementos.

Te adjunto un código de ejemplo que hace lo que buscas:

```css
.login-header {
    width: 350px;
    height: 40px;
}
.button {
    width: 200px;
}
.login-header, .registro {
    background: radial-gradient(95.14% 7284.37% at 2.57% 20%, #ffc24b 0%, #ffa13a 100%);
}
.button, #regForm {
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.login-header,
.login p {
    font-family: Ubuntu;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #444444;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13.0408px;
}
#regForm {
    height: 500px;
    width: 350px;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-5">

    <div class="card mx-auto" id="regForm">
        <h2 class="login-header rounded-top">¡Registrese y obtenga los libros que más quiera!</h2>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form action="">
                <div class="form-group col-12 p-0 mb-4">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" />
                </div><!--//form-group-->
                <div class="form-group col-12 p-0 mb-4">
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" />
                </div><!--//form-group-->
                <div class="form-group col-12 p-0 mb-4">
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" id="password" required />
                </div><!--//form-group-->
                <div class="form-group col-12 p-0 mb-4">
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Confirmar contraseña" id="confirm_password" required />
                </div><!--//form-group-->
                <div class="form-group col-12 text-center mb-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn button registro" id="submit">
                        Registrarse
                    </button>
                </div><!--//form-group-->
                <div class="form-group col-12 text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn button bg-white" id="submit">
                        Google button
                    </button>
                </div><!--//form-group-->
            </form>
        </div><!--//card-body-->
    </div><!--//card-->

</div><!--//container-->
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, Ariel, me es muy util tu respuesta, héroe sin capa